# sed to replace a line with regular expression

Tags: sed

I want to use sed to replace the  ip addresses in the below entry.

```
1500.arp1.akaarp.net.00000000.7ac112c6.123456.6 30 IN TXT "198.18.193.23,2509.417\;198.18.193.25,2609.417\;198.18.193.27,2709.417"
```

1500.arp1.akaarp.net.00000000.7ac112c6.123456.6 30 IN TXT "`19.18.19.27,1110.400`\;198.18.193.25,2609.417\;198.18.193.27,2709.417"

I tried the following :

sed -i s/"198.18.193.23,2409.417\;198.18.193.25,2609.417\;198.18.193.27,2709.417"/"198.18.19.27,1110.400"/  filename.txt

The above entry works if there is only one ip address in the actual entry. If there are multiple ip addresses separated by regular expressions this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is extremely unclear but if you just want to replace whatever list of IP addresses is between quotes then that's just:

```
$ sed 's/"[^"]*"/"198.18.19.27,1110.400"/' file
1500.arp1.akaarp.net.00000000.7ac112c6.123456.6 30 IN TXT "198.18.19.27,1110.400"
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to clarify your requirements. In particular explain what these 2 sentences in your question mean:

1. The above entry works if there is only one ip address in the actual entry.
2. If there are multiple ip addresses separated by regular expressions this doesn't work.

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat file
1500.arp1.akaarp.net.00000000.7ac112c6.123456.6 30 IN TXT "198.18.193.23,2509.417\;198.18.193.25,2609.417\;198.18.193.27,2709.417"
```

Answer (score 0):

triple the backslashes and it will work: BTW, the quotes were misplaced, or you have to escape them too.

You have to escape:

- the backslashes from the shell and from sed, hence the need of 3 backslashes.
- the dots but it still works like this because it matches any character so dot matches too.

So the quickfix is

```
sed -i s/"198.18.193.23,2509.417\\\;198.18.193.25,2609.417\\\;198.18.193.27,2709.417"/"198.18.19.27,1110.400"/ file.txt
```

2 problems:

- quotes are completely ignored by sed because the shell consumes them
- dots are considered as wildcards

Consequently, this string would be replaced, which is maybe not what you want (I replaced the dots by digits & letters):

```
1500.arp1.akaarp.net.00000000.7ac112c6.123456.6 30 IN TXT 1987187193723,2509.417\;198718z193v25,2609k417\;198.18.193.27,2709.417
```

A cleaner fix would be

```
sed -i "s/\"198\.18\.193\.23,2509\.417\\\;198\.18\.193\.25,2609\.417\\\;198\.18\.193\.27,2709\.417\"/\"198.18.19.27,1110.400\"/" file.txt
```

If you want to randomize output, to replace, say, 1110 by a random number between 1 and 100, do this (no need for `shuf`):

```
sed -i "s/\"198\.18\.193\.23,2509\.417\\\;198\.18\.193\.25,2609\.417\\\;198\.18\.193\.27,2709\.417\"/\"198.18.19.27,$(($RANDOM%100+1)).400\"/" file.txt
```

Comment: That works. Thanks. Quick question. Is it possible to use SHUF with sed. Something like below. Shuf is to genrate a random number.  I want to genrate a random number in place of 2609.                                                sed -i s/"198.18.193.23,2509.417\\\;198.18.193.25,2609.417\\\;198.18.193.27,2709.417"/"198.18.19.27,shuf -i 1-100 -n 1"/ dns.txt

Comment: To get a random value simply use $RANDOM unless you need big values, which is not the case here. post edited.

Comment: Never enclose any script in double quotes, just enclose in singe quotes and then surround the part you NEED the shell to access in single quotes again, e.g. `sed 's/'"$var"'/whatever/'`, not `sed "s/$var/whataver/"` as the latter introduces unnecessary caveats and complexity, as seen in this answer.